# Why do we use do-while loop when there are better loops available?

Tags: java, loops, do-while

I didn't find any practical use of do-while loop. As a studied we don't have control over the do-while loop when it executes for the first time and everything which can be done with   do-while loop, can be don with while or for loop (assuming).

**My Question is:** Is there any situation where we use a do-while loop, or any particular situation where it gives more reliable results as compared to for and while loops?

Comment: you perform something before evaluating result,  but perform atleast once

Comment: You can write everything without `for` loops too, but sometimes it's nicer semantically.

Comment: Why any loops at all when we have recursion?

Comment: Readability is underrated.

Comment: @Ingo - "_To iterate is human, to recurse divine."_ — L. Peter Deutch

Comment: You simply do not have enough experience.  There are many cases where do/while is perfect, and others where it's maybe a little less so but still exposes the logic of the app better than any other structure.  Consider that all one really needs is if/goto, but [we tried that once and it didn't work too well](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.92.4846&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

it's useful for repeating an action until it's correct

```
String input;

...

do
{
    input = getInput();

} while(isValid(input));
```

to do that with another loop, you'd have to write `input = getInput();` twice

Comment: That's a fairly useless loop since `input` goes out of scope when the loop exits. Declare the variable `input` before the loop and negate the condition; then it would actually be useful.

Answer (score 7):

`do`/`while` is *precisely* suitable when you always want to execute at least once, but you want to check whether or not to keep going at the *end* of the loop instead of at the start.

You can easily emulate it with a while loop, but sometimes the code becomes less clear that way. All three loop types can be emulated with each other, with more or less mess - but as all three are available, you should just pick the most appropriate loop for the job in hand.

I personally use both `while` loops and `do`/`while` loops less often than `for` loops, but *sometimes* a `do`/`while` is the most readable option.

Answer (score 3):

Might as well say "I didn't find any practical use of for loop...everything which can be done with for loop, can be don with while loop (assuming)".

Technically you can replace any loop with literally any other loop given enough finangling with the loop guards and such. Some loops are just nicer to read than others.

`do-while` is primarily "better" if you want to perform an action *at least once*, e.g. asking for input, or getting some random value until it fits into some constraint. You *can* do such an action by performing the action once outside a "regular" loop and looping from there, but it's just neater to use `do-while`.

Answer (score -2):

Do-while has generally better performance characteristics if the loop body *must* execute *at least* once. If you reformulate a do-while into a while/for, you add an extra evaluation of the loop exit condition.

Also, do-while(false) is usable as a structured alternative for deeply nested if conditions:

```
do {
   if (!condition1)
       break;
   if (!condition2)
       break;
   if (!conditionN)
       break;
   // do something
} while (false);
```

instead of:

```
if (condition1) {
    if (condition2) {
        if (conditionN) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(condition1 && condition2 && condition3)`

Comment: Thats only practical if condition is *simple*. If you need to navigate relationships and check for nulls/conditions its not applicable. It can also quickly lead to bracket messes with non-trivial conditions.

Comment: IMHO it's a very questionable piece of code. You use the loop not for its straight purpose and it looks very unusual for me (and, I believe, for the majority of developers) and it makes me think that some complex logic is being applied here, not just some condition checks. This completely ruins idea of any "code beauty".
I think there is always a better solution - to simplify complex conditions to several boolean vars, or to create a separate method instead of do-while block (where you can use "return;" if needed), etc.

Comment: @Durandal consider the code:  `if (condition1 && condition2)`.  if `condition1` is false, than `condition2` will never actually get executed.  This means that you can write something like `if(val != null && val.subval == otherVal)` and it won't break.

Comment: You just insist on using *simple*, *trivial* conditions. Thats fine, but the real world isn't always so simple and nicely designed. Consider this: Check if order has extra info object attached, if yes check that field status is "pending" and that field "clerk" has been set, then do... (a simple buisness rule). Of *course* you could write either if (order.getExtraInfo() != null && order.getExtraInfo().getStatus().equals(pending) && order.getExtraInfo().getClerk() != null) *or* if ((ExtraInfo i = order.getExtraInfo()) != null && i.getStatue().equals(pending) && i.getClerk() != null).

Comment: @AndreiBuneyeu Its a known idiom, considering agoogle search for "do while false" leads to several hits for several languages here on stack overflow. If you insists on using only idioms *everyone* knows you can't write any code.

Comment: @Durandal So, how is your do-while loop better in that case?

Comment: @SamIam It remains readable even if variables are created between conditions, thats all. You don't really want to tell me you find those if alternatives more readable, do you?

Comment: This is several years old now, but I agree with the majority here. Using a loop for a non-looping syntax counter-intuitive. As stated by Andrei, would it not be better to abstract this to a method and do the following: `if (!condition) return;` You can then follow this same pattern with guard statements all the way until you are ready to execute `//do something`. No looping required. This seems much more readable to me as a programmer will first assume that a loop will loop more than once.